# How to wait for MySQL database migrations in a docker container to complete before moving to the next stage in Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

In my Jenkinsfile, I have several stages for my pipeline. In one of the stage, I use Docker to spin up a MySQL database and then run some database migrations to set up the database tables and some seeder data. In the following Jenkins stage, I do some unit tests which need communications to the database and all the unit tests are carried out outside Docker. The problem is that Jenkins stage starts before the migrations complete in the previous stage, hence the unit tests will fail, because the database tables are not ready.

What I have tried is to let the code execution to wait for certain amount of time until the migrations complete. But the waiting period is hardcoded which I think is not flexible and it will cause the pipeline to fail if migrations take longer than the waiting period.

Please find my current code below:

```
stage('Bring up MySQL Docker') {
   steps {
      sh 'pwd'
      sh 'sudo npm run playpen-stop'
      // this starts a docker container to spin up a MySQL database and run migraions
      sh 'sudo npm run playpen-start'
   }
}

stage('Unit testing backend/products') {
   when {
      expression { GIT_CHANGES.contains('backend/products') == true }
   }
   steps {
      dir ('backend/products') {
         sh 'pwd'
         //todo: this is a hack to wait until migrations are complete
         sh 'sleep 40'
         //todo: hack to fix permissioning issues
         sh 'sudo rm -rf node_modules/'
         sh 'sudo DOTENV=.env.playpen npm run test'
       }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be something like this from the [jenkins documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/):

```
 sh 'while ! mysqladmin ping -hdb --silent; do sleep 1; done'
```

This should be easily adaptable. But still not a nice solution.